# Custom PostGIS function not visible in pg_tileserv layer list

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tiles, pg-tileserv

I have created a new PostgreSQL function whose code is below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."my_test"(
    layerid integer,
    z integer,
    x integer,
    y integer)
    RETURNS bytea
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    STABLE PARALLEL SAFE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
mvt_results bytea;  -- Return bytea

BEGIN
WITH lines AS (
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            mj.map_job_id AS map_job_id,
            mj.map_job_id AS "mapJobId",
            ml.geom AS geom,
            mft.map_feature_type_name AS featureType,
            mft.map_feature_type_name AS "featureType",
            mg.map_group_name AS featureGroup,
            mg.map_group_name AS "featureGroup",
            mla.map_group_id AS featureGroupId,
            mla.map_group_id AS "featureGroupId",
            mla.map_feature_type_id AS featureTypeId,
            mla.map_feature_type_id AS "featureTypeId",
            mla.map_line_id AS featureId,
            mla.map_line_id AS "featureId",
            mla.map_line_id_comp AS feature,
            mla.map_line_id_comp AS "featureName",
            'line' AS "featureClass",
            'line' AS "tileType",
            layerid AS "layerId",
            false AS "isAnnotation"
        FROM
            PUBLIC.map_jobs mj
        INNER JOIN PUBLIC.map_lines_attributes mla on
            mj.map_job_id = mla.map_job_id
        INNER JOIN PUBLIC.map_lines ml on
            ml.map_line_id = ml.map_line_id
        INNER JOIN public.map_group mg on
            mla.map_group_id = mg.map_group_id
        INNER JOIN public.map_feature_type mft on
            mft.map_feature_type_id = mla.map_feature_type_id
        WHERE
            mj.is_deleted = false
            AND mj.tenant_id = 1  
            AND mla.map_layer_id = layerid 
    )
    UNION  ALL 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            mj.map_job_id AS map_job_id,
            mj.map_job_id AS "mapJobId",
            mal.geom AS geom,
            mft.map_feature_type_name AS featureType,
            mft.map_feature_type_name AS "featureType",
            mg.map_group_name AS featureGroup,
            mg.map_group_name AS "featureGroup",
            mala.map_group_id AS featureGroupId,
            mala.map_group_id AS "featureGroupId",
            mala.map_feature_type_id AS featureTypeId,
            mala.map_feature_type_id AS "featureTypeId",
            mala.map_annotation_line_id AS featureId,
            mala.map_annotation_line_id AS "featureId",
            mala.map_annotation_line_id_comp AS feature,
            mala.map_annotation_line_id_comp AS "featureName",
            'line_annotation' AS "featureClass",
            'line' AS "tileType",
            layerid AS "layerId",
            true AS "isAnnotation"
        FROM
            public.map_jobs mj
        INNER JOIN public.map_annotation_lines_attributes mala on
            mj.map_job_id = mala.map_job_id
        INNER JOIN public.map_annotation_lines mal on
            mal.map_annotation_line_id = mala.map_annotation_line_id
        INNER JOIN public.map_feature_type mft on
            mft.map_feature_type_id = mala.map_feature_type_id
        INNER JOIN public.map_group mg on
            mg.map_group_id = mala.map_group_id
        WHERE
            mj.is_deleted = false
            AND mj.tenant_id = 1 
            AND mala.map_layer_id = layerid
    )
),
bounds AS (
    SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y) AS geom
),
mvt_geom AS (
    SELECT
        ST_AsMVTGeom(
            ST_Transform(ST_Force2D(ST_SetSRID(l.geom, 4326)), 3857),
             bounds.geom,
            NULL,
            256
        ) AS geom,
        map_job_id,
        "mapJobId",
        featureType,
        "featureType",
        featureGroup,
        "featureGroup",
        featureGroupId,
        "featureGroupId",
        featureTypeId,
        "featureTypeId",
        feature,
        "featureName",
        featureId, 
        "featureId", 
        "featureClass", 
        "layerId",
        "isAnnotation"
    FROM
        lines l,
        bounds
    WHERE ST_Intersects(l.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
)
SELECT
    ST_AsMVT(mvt_geom.*)
INTO mvt_results
FROM
    mvt_geom;

RETURN mvt_results;

END;

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public."my_test"(integer, integer, integer, integer)
    OWNER TO sitemap_prod_db_admin;
```

as mentioned in the docs https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/pg_tileserv/1.0.9/usage/function-layers/
but when I try to access it using pg_tileserv I dont see it in function layers

[image: layer list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this, so for any those who face same problem I am posting this answer. pg_tileserv expects first three arguments of function layer to be z,x,y so by changing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."my_test"(
layerid integer,
z integer,
x integer,
y integer)
```

to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."my_test"(
z integer,
x integer,
y integer,
layerid integer)
```

its working fine now.